# Create a pie chart using a formula

Tags: google-sheets, worksheet-function, google-sheets-charts

I'm using Google's monthly budget sheet to track my expenses.

I need to have a pie chart but I don't want it to be floating around in the sheet and be in a specific cell(s). So I thought a formula like `Sparkline` might be the answer. But is there such a formula? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

For the moment at least, I think not. Try a pie chart using SPARKLINE and the error is:

> Function SPARKLINE parameter 2 option charttype value is pie. It should be one of: 'line', 'column', 'winloss', 'bar'.

You might consider embedding an [IMAGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093333) instead but I doubt worth the bother ever were the image to be dynamic, that would be yet more bother.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a pie chart inside a cell doing the following:

1. Create a floating pie chart, move it to it's own sheet and publish it as a static image;
2. Get the published URL and use it in an IMAGE function inside a cell

Then tweak the chart formatting as you like.
I recommend removing title and legends and adding the labels with a large font inside the slices, plus checking the option to maximize.